# Group by key and append values to a List

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

I am trying to read list and get key and value pair

```
 from itertools import groupby
    a=['x.site1.ca.zilla.wipro.com',
       'y.site2.ca.zilla.wipro.com',
    'z.site1.co.zilla.wipro.com']
    d={}
    z=[]
    for x in (a):
        l=x.split(".")
        if(d[l[2]] in d):
            d[l[2]].append(l[1])
        else:
            d[l[2]] = []
```

I am getting Key Error? Why is this wrong?

Expected output:

```
 {ca:[site1,site2],co:[site1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: You're getting KeyError because in first iteration, value `l[2]` isn't in dictionary `d` - so `d[l[2]]` throws exception.

```
a=['x.site1.ca.zilla.wipro.com',
   'y.site2.ca.zilla.wipro.com',
   'z.site1.co.zilla.wipro.com']

out = {}
for x in a:
    x = x.split('.')
    out.setdefault(x[2], []).append(x[1])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'ca': ['site1', 'site2'], 'co': ['site1']}
```

Comment: It works!!, Can you please explain to me why my code is wrong?

Comment: I have written else " d[l[2]] = [] " doenst this handle key Error?